# Is the use of self-tracking entities efficient for huge and complex object graphs?

Tags: c#, .net, orm, entity-framework-4, performance

1) Since self-tracking entities do not support lazy loading, are they intended to be used with not-so-big entities graphs because of efficiency?

2) Which solution do you suggest instead of using self-tracking entities? DTOs?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not a good conclusion. Lazy loading is convenient but can also become a performance problem, with small graphs as well as big.

There is no substitute for a good design that will limit the # of records required.